# Get the public facebook Page feed and photos in android

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-4.0

Can i get the details of the page like(page feed,page display pic, photos, videos, number of likes etc.,) of a public page

**Note** : The details i'm having about the page was only The PAGE NAME and i'm having the access token and my profile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use "/{page_id}/feed" url to get Particular page feeds.

```
new GraphRequest(token, "/{page_id}/feed", params, HttpMethod.GET, this).executeAsync();
```

You can get page_id from "/me/accounts" to get all pages page_id then you can get your desired page_id.

```
new GraphRequest(token, "/me/accounts", params, HttpMethod.GET, this).executeAsync();
```

**EDIT:**

First You can get page_id of all liked pages using "/me/likes".

```
new GraphRequest(token, "/me/likes", params, HttpMethod.GET, this).executeAsync();
```

then you can get page_id from response get page feeds and photos from page_id

I hope it helps!

Comment: If the Page was not under my accounts. Then how could i get the page id

Comment: And also /me/accounts gives me empty data

Comment: if i want to get the page id of the unliked page?

Comment: And i'm getting the empty data with response code:200

Comment: are your recieve empty data in liked page?

Comment: {Response:  responseCode: 200, graphObject: {"data":[]}, error: null}-- this is my GraphResponse -- When i used    /me/likes

Comment: I am checking get back to you in few min

Comment: Currently Facebook has not provided getting unliked page id from any of their api. you can only get liked page id. it is possible in web but not in android

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. But neither m not getting the liked pages

Comment: for me: me/likes works in Graph api explorer. it will return likes pages and its id's

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87252/discussion-between-user3607798-and-rajesh-jadav).